# Best calculus book for physics

Tags: resource-recommendations, education, mathematics, calculus

Are spivak and apostol calculus book good even from a physics point of view for learning calculus?

I have a basic understanding of calculus but want to learn in depth more physics and for this I require more calculus

Answer (score 3):

You can try out [Introduction to Calculus and Analysis](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/354065058X) by Courant. The first volume deals with single variable calculus and the second volume deals with multiple variable calculus.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what your position is now. But, for anyone starting to read calculus, I would recommend Silivanus P. Thompson's amazing book, *Calculus Made Easy*

http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/33283

Its available freely, and is a masterpiece. However, for a much more advanced or rigorous footing, I would recommend Spivak over Apostol. I have read Apostol myself. Its good but not as good as Spivak.